# Asterisk simultaneous outgoing calls with media

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, outgoing-call

Is it possible to originate several outgoing calls with Asterisk taking several media streams from some program's outputs (or from ALSA/etc playbacks or from FIFO-pipes)? Fully automated solution, no human intervention required.

**Issue**

I have software which generates several (separated) audio streams. It can stream into ALSA/OSS/PulseAudio devices or FIFO-pipes (named pipes).

I need to resend this audio to my STT/ASR service provider via SIP (the only interface supported by provider) continuously.

**Current workaround**

My current test case is to record short files and use them with simple call-files like this one:

```
Channel: SIP/asr.provider.com/12345
Application: Playback
Data: chunk-filename-here
MaxRetries: 2
```

All works fine, but I need to make this process continuous (dial on start and keep connection alive as long as possible). I guess I need to replace `Application: Playback` with other appropriate application in call-files or in my dial-plan context.

**UPD**

As follows from `chan_oss` and `chan_oss` docs, both of them are not suitable:

> With 1.2.x versions of Asterisk, only one OSS channel can be created and only one call can be placed to/from the OSS channel at a given time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see chan_alsa and chan_oss.

You also may require confbridge to split it.

Comment: A you sure it is possible to start __several (simultaneous) calls__ with ALSA/OSS and confbridge? Documentation for this chans says otherwise.

Comment: Send alsa to confbridge, send any number of callls from confbridge to destination. Or use JACK.

Comment: But `chan_alsa` allows to create just one call. And I don't see how `confbridge` allows to solve this limitation.

Comment: Cofnbridge do conference, i.e bridge as many calls to one sound space as you wish.